# Plot .csv file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

I am new to python and I am trying to learn. I need to graph a .csv file but I don't know which is the best way to get a graph as shown below: [image]

[image]

I tried to read the file with the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')  
print (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have time-series data. I will suggest to first read more about plot libraries in python and then try plotting. Below are some links to python plot gallerias. please go to there and match the plot and try the code with your data. best of luck

[Pandas Plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/visualization.html),
[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html),
[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html)